# Sparx Enterprise Architetc Pattern Integration with a Custom Toolbox

Tags: modeling, enterprise-architect

I have a problem in adding a pattern in Sparx Enterprise Architect.

I created a diagram and then saved as a pattern as is shown in the following figure.

[image]

In addition, I designed my own custom toolbox using MDG technology, and I want to integrate that diagram with my toolbox to be something similar to the following figure

[image]

I just need to integrate that pattern (XML file) with my custom toolbox in MDG technology.

Comment: Your question seems to be too broad. SO is no tutorial place. You need to dig into the help or other resources to get a basic idea how to create toolbox entries.

Comment: I did it, thanks a lot Mr. Kilian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much straight forward. Once you create your MDG

[image]

check the `Patterns` box. Now the next after the profiles will ask for your patterns:

[image]

Locate your pattern files (best they were saved in a separate directory) and include your pattern(s).

Your MDG should now include the added pattern(s).

To refer the pattern in a toolbox you need to add `<profileID>::<patternName>(UMLPattern)` manually where appropriate.

Comment: I followed these steps and I choose the xml file of the pattern, but nothing happened. The MDG is created and the all components are created but pattern not. .

Comment: You mean, it's not in the toolbox? Have you verified the pattern is fine by including it in the View/Resources?

Comment: No I don't, how I can verify it because I just design a normal diagram and press publish then publish diagram as a pattern

Comment: Open the mentioned dialog and include the pattern in `UML Patterns` from the context. You should then be able to drag it from there to a diagram.

Comment: I did the following, I import the pattern into Pattern from Resources, but it still not a part of my custom toolbox

Comment: Mr. @Kilian, It working the pattern is drag into the workspace, but I have only one question how I can add that pattern to my custom toolbox

Comment: @abdel-kaderMagdy seems like your'e using the resources window to drag your pattern, but you can add it to your toolbox via toolbox profiles

Comment: @Hue yes you are right, I would like to add the created pattern into my custom toolbox. As you mentioned above, I can add that one using Toolbox profile, but the problem the components of the toolbox profile are should be a type: Class. Actually, I have no idea how I can make it